# How do I recover my serial number for Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 for Windows?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-premiere, serial-number

I purchased a new computer and am attempting to reinstall Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 for Windows but I no longer have the original serial number. The software was purchased physically from a store and I cannot find the original box. I never registered my copy to an Adobe account, but I still have access to my old PC with CS6 installed.

How do I recover or transfer the serial number from my existing Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 install so I can use it on a new PC?

[image: Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 Family installer asking for serial number]

Comment: I suggest you call Adobe Support. They may be able to assist you with information you provide.  Otherwise you may be out of luck. You can also try Recover Keys if the old computer runs.

Comment: If you still have access to the PC, and you can boot into Windows, Amt3.log might have the information you seek. Third-party tools that suggests it will list the key most certainly malware unless it comes from Adobe directly

Comment: Since you still have the old computer and can log in, have you tried method 1 from [Adobe Photoshop Cs6 Serial Key 94fbr Serial Number](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.photo.equipment.medium-format/c/F60KzyxNiYc?pli=1) opening the application up and going to the `Help` menu option and checking `System Information`? They also have other possible methods listed, but that one is the simplest.

Comment: @DrZoo There is no System Information option in Premier Pro CS6.